# Error: The values of --overrides does not seem to be valid JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, graphql, load-testing

I am trying for load testing using easygraphql-lt, my code look like this, but i am getting this error

Error: The values of --overrides does not seem to be valid JSON.

Any Suggestions?

```
{
    "config": {
        "url": "http://localhost:3002/",
        "name": "Without Load Testing.......",
        "queryFile": true,
        "duration": 10,
        "arrivalRate": 10,
        "withOutput": true
    },
    "args": {
        "missionTemplates": {
            "_id": "68e4b4f0-b3df-11eb-aa42-1d83d5dd4339"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you showed isn't code, it's just a piece of JSON. Show the full code that uses the JSON data. My gut feeling says you are passing it into a shell command line and forgot to escape it.

Comment: i just created lt.json this file as i shared the code and running it from command line using  npx easygraphql-lt lt.json  this command using terminal. do i need to add it anything in it ? i just refere this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ah-8_SdHjmE&lc=UgxllW5O1QL__AYeHMh4AaABAg

Comment: test this json with some json validation tool

Comment: Maybe there is a BOM (byte order mark) in front of the file?